# Does the following article excerpt assume that the call stack grows from lower address to higher address?

Tags: c++, c, mips, callstack

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) on call stack (derived from [University of Maryland content](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)) says the following in regard to the below image:

> The locations of all other fields in the frame can be defined relative
>   either to the top of the frame, **as negative offsets of the stack
>   pointer**, or relative to the top of the frame below, **as positive
>   offsets of the frame pointer**. The location of the frame pointer itself
>   must inherently be defined as a negative offset of the stack pointer.

Is it true only if we assume that the stack grows from lower to higher address in this case?

[image]

Comment: the picture itself does not imply higher to lower nor lower to higher, top of stack could be the bottom dixie cup or it could be the top cafeteria plate, both are "top of stack".    negative offset of the stack pointer and positive offsets to the frame pointer are the answer to your question.

Comment: @dwelch The excerpt above is not about the growth of the stack, it's about the relative location of the fields in the frame. In such a case, doesn't negative offset to the stack pointer only suggest that the stack pointer is at a higher address?

Comment: exactly as does the frame pointer comment(s).  Together they imply that the stack pointer address is greater than the frame pointer and the stack pointer is at "top of stack".  So an upward growing stack from an address perspective.

Comment: @dwelch How can the stack pointer address be greater than the frame pointer address unless the stack grows from lower to higher/greater address?

Comment: exactly, okay sorry when I said upward growing stack I should have said grows toward a higher address...

Comment: @dwelch So can you please confirm what I have asked so that I can close the question? I have asked if in this case the stack grows from lower to higher memory address.

Comment: I repeat: exactly as does the frame pointer comment(s). Together they imply that the stack pointer address is greater than the frame pointer and the stack pointer is at "top of stack".  So it implies that the stack grows from lower to higher memory  addresses.

Comment: @dwelch Thank you :-)

Comment: There is a better diagram: http://post.queensu.ca/~trd/377/tut5/stack.html The wiki one doesn't show the save for the frame [aka base] pointer (FP) and thus the FP is one-off. It also said: _A diagram like this can be drawn in either direction as long as the placement of the top, and so direction of stack growth, is understood._ Under most arches [and MIPS] stack grows downward hi-to-lo, so the diagram is inverted.